# distcp: How to avoid flattening dir if there's only one file in hdfs to s3 copying

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hdfs, distcp

Currently my hdfs structure is:

/data/xxx/xxx/2014

/data/xxx/xxx/2015

/data/xxx/xxx/2016

two files under 2015, two under 2016, only one file in 2014

i use this command to copy them seperately:

hadoop  distcp  -Dfs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId="mykey" -Dfs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey="mysecret"  /data/xxx/xxx/2014* s3n://bucket/emr/xxx/xxx/year=2014/

somehow it appears to be

PRE year=2015/

PRE year=2016/

44324255 year=2014

The file in 2014 doesn't store in s3 folder, but as a separate file.(This case doesn't happen to 2015 and 2016 since there are multiple files)

Is there any way to make it store as  PRE year=2014/ ???

I do not want this cmd flatten the directory hierarchy.